# Quadratic Twists on Elliptic Curves- John Coates

Tags: nt.number-theory

I was actually facing difficulty in Lemma 2.4 of Section 2 (Generalization of Birch's Lemma).-Quadratic Twists on Elliptic Curves- Proceeding of London Mathematical Society. I don't understand why there is a unique $\sigma\in Gal(JK/Q)$  and how the restriction of $Gal(JK/Q)$ can end up giving Complex conjugation and Frobenius Endomorphism. And also what is Chebotarevs Density theorem being applied on. As I don't see how $\sum_r$ is the discriminant?.

Comment: Your question is more likely to get an answer if you make it self contained.

Comment: Unless you are very lucky to get someone very familiar with this particular paper to answer, such questions make little sense.